# Mvvmcross: Cannot create MvxRecyclerAdapter in OnCreate of an Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I use MvxRecyclerView in [Mvvmcross Support RecyclerView library](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView)

The problem is that MvxRecyclerView cannot be inflated in an Activity (but Fragment works well). It seems that MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current() return null in MvxRecyclerAdapter constructor.

Could you please tell me how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe OnCreate is too early in the lifecycle to get a context. You could try to do this in the OnCreateView method. Otherwise i would suggest to set your own instance of the MvxRecyclerAdapter where you put in the context in the constructor.

```
var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
if (recyclerView != null)
{
    recyclerView.Adapter = new MvxRecyclerAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);
}
```